# Dynamically changing favicon back and forth multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, favicon, userscripts

I am running a userscript (using tampermonkey) on a site, and I have a function which is called each time something else on the page changes.

I have a value stored in something called `Available`. If this is 0, then I want to use the standard favicon for the site. Otherwise, I want a red box added to the favicon with text displaying the value of `Available`.

This works initially, however after `Available` goes > 0, then == 0, then > 0 again, it stops adding the red box with white text on top.

The code is definitely reaching the key point each time, as my console log shows the value for `Available` is being triggered.

Here's what I have:

```
if(Available > 0){
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = 16;canvas.height = 16;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var img = new Image();
    img.src = '/favicon.ico';
    img.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#F00";
        ctx.fillRect(10, 7, 6, 8);
        ctx.fillStyle = '#FFFFFF';
        ctx.font = 'bold 10px sans-serif';
        ctx.fillText(Available, 10, 14);

        var link = document.createElement('link');
        link.type = 'image/x-icon';
        link.rel = 'shortcut icon';
        link.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/x-icon");
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
    };
}
else {
    var canvas2 = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas2.width = 16;
    canvas2.height = 16;
    var ctx2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');

    var img2 = new Image();
    img2.src = '/favicon.ico';
    img2.onload = function() {
        ctx2.drawImage(img2, 0, 0);

        var link2 = document.createElement('link');
        link2.type = 'image/x-icon';
        link2.rel = 'shortcut icon';
        link2.href = canvas2.toDataURL("image/x-icon");
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link2);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most likely need to remove the previously-added icon links, so the browser doesn't just keep using the first one you added:

```js
var oldLinks = document.querySelectorAll('link[rel*="icon"]');

for (var i = oldLinks.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
  var ln = oldLinks[i],
      pn = ln.parentNode;

  pn.removeChild(ln);
}

if (Available > 0) {
  // as before
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend a slightly more robust selector like `link[rel*="icon"]`